# Pairwise Commuting Elements Generating a Certain Subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be some complex algebra (i.e., algebra over the complex numbers), and let $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathcal{A}$ be pairwise commuting elements (i.e., $a_i a_j = a_j a_i$ for all $i,j=1,...,n$). Call a subalgebra $\mathcal{B}$ inversion closed if $x \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x$ is invertible, then $x^{-1} \in \mathcal{B}$.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the smallest inversion closed subalgebra containing $a_1,...,a_n$. I am trying to show that $\mathcal{B}$ must be commutative. Intuitively this is clear. But I am having trouble explicitly describing the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ to show that it is  commutative? Does it consist of all rational polynomials in the variables $a_1,...,a_n$?

**EDIT**

Maybe it's easier than I thought. Here's an idea. Let $\mathcal{C} = \{ \frac{f(a_1,...,a_n)}{g(a_1,...,a_n)} \mid f,g \in \Bbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n], g \neq 0\}$. I think that this is clearly a inversion closed subalgebra which contains $a_1,...,a_n$, so $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ (perhaps equality holds, but it doesn't matter). Then somewhat tedious calculations show that $\mathcal{C}$ is commutative, so $\mathcal{B}$ must be commutative, being a subalgebra of $\mathcal{C}$. Does this sound right?

Hmm...but does $\mathcal{C}$ even "live" inside of $\mathcal{A}$. I'm not even sure the notation $\frac{f(a_1,...,a_n)}{g(a_1,...,a_n)}$ makes sense. I suppose it makes sense if you interpret it as $f(a_1,...,a_n) g(a_1,...,a_n)^{-1}$, but just because $g(a_1,....,a_n) \neq 0$ doesn't mean it is invertible.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but to get the smallest inversion closed subalgebra you can take the localization by the invertible elements, and prove that this is inversion closed.

Comment: You have to prove that the inverses commute too.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood it correctly, the elements of the subalgebra are ${\Bbb C}$-linear combinations of the form
$$a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\cdots a_n^{m_n},$$
where $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n$ are integers.

Comment: But will this subalgebra be inversion closed?

Comment: It's not that simple. There's no reason why the inverse of, for example, $a_1+a_2$ should be expressible in this way.